# wp_options not returning value for logged out users?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have saved my custom plugin settings inside wp_options table, but when I try to access them using "get_option" function it returns me undefined for logout users, but when I logged in it returns me the accurate value saved in the table, anyone can help me why is that happening or is it the default behavior?

this is how I am adding the option in wp_options table:

```
add_option('token_limit' , $token_limit);
```

and this is how I am accessing it:

```
$token_limit = get_option('token_limit');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add
`update_option('token_limit' , $token_limit);`

The function `add_option()` only add the option, without value